# Django issue with requests in getting json

Tags: python, django, json

I have a front-end server that is getting some JSON data from my backend server. Both servers are running Django. This is the exact code that gets the json data..

```
def View(request):
  r = requests.get(path)
  return HttpResponse(r.json())
```

However, I am running into a strange problem today where the call completes successfully ONCE after restarting the server. If I run the following code: -

```
def View(request):
  r = requests.get(path)
  r = requests.get(path)
  return HttpResponse(r.json())
```

This works successfully as well.

However, on the second time that View() is called, I get an error. This is what the error message says:

```
"uWSGI exceptions catcher for "GET /api/v1/backend/" (request plugin: "python", modifier1: 0)
Exception: TypeError: http header value must be a string
Exception class: TypeError
Exception message: http header value must be a string"
```

Clearly, the error is being thrown on my backend server, but I only changed some templates on the frontend today. I am at a loss as to what has caused this problem to start occurring today. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4):

give it the right json header:

```
return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: `mimetype` is deprecated in 1.6 - better use `content_type`. But +1 anyway.

Comment: @Guy thanks for the response. However the problem ended up being with some newrelic code that I had on the backend. I have been banging my head against the wall for the last 5 hours and tried everything and it worked as soon as I disabled new relic monitoring.